# Sharing a video to Facebook with OG tags via an iFrame embed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video-streaming, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to find out if it is possible to set the OG tags, Flash/HTML5 player embed code and share button in one page. Then embed this in another page via an iFrame embed and then when the Facebook share button is selected via the iFrame it shares all the OG tags but rather than the player page URL it links back to the parent pages URL.

Is it possible to do this without having to add any tags to the parent page so they are all contained in the iFrame page?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a `og:url` tag in Open Graph Tags.
If you know the parent page URL of the embedded content, you can set `og:url` parameter with the parent page URL.
Then, it behaves like the way you share the parent page.

Comment: Thanks Cebirci. But then don't I still need to put some OG tags in the parent page? I have tried just setting the URL to the parent page but it seems to just then share the parent URL without reading the OG tags in the iframe. Is this something you have successfully done with tags on the original page being transferred to the new URL?

Comment: What do you share on Facebook? The iframe URL or parent page URL? If share button is on the iframe you may share iframe URL. My suggestion is that to share iframe URL on Facebook, to put og tags on the iframe, and giving og:url value as parent page URL.

Comment: I want to share the parent URL but use the OG tags from the iFrame. I can do it by sharing the parent URL and include the og:url in the parent page which links back to the iframe URL that includes all the video tags. Now what I am trying to do is get rid of the og:url tags in the parent url maybe by somehow parsing this in the Facebook Share URL but am not sure if this can be done.